# Produce pie chart subplots for unique results in groupby?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

What is the best way to produce pie charts for unique values in a Dataframe?

I have a DataFrame that shows number of services by county. I would like to produce a group of pie charts for every county that shows the count of services in that county. I've tried a variety of different approaches without much success.

Here's my data

print(mdfgroup)

```
    County     Service    ServiceCt
0   Alamance    Literacy          1
1   Alamance   Technical          1
2   Alamance  Vocational          4
3    Chatham    Literacy          3
4    Chatham   Technical          2
5    Chatham  Vocational          1
6     Durham    Literacy          1
7     Durham   Technical          1
8     Durham  Vocational          1
9     Orange    Literacy          1
10      Wake    Literacy          2
11      Wake   Technical          2
```

So there would be one chart for Alamance with slices for literacy, technical, vocational; a chart for Chatham, Durham, etc. Slice size would be based on ServiceCt.

I've been experimenting with a lot of different approaches but I'm not sure what the most efficient would be. I tried but below it doesn't really break it down by county and it's not resulting in any graphs.

```
for i, row in enumerate(mdfgroup.itertuples(),1):
       plt.figure()
       plt.pie(row.ServiceCt,labels=row.Service,
       startangle=90,frame=True, explode=0.2,radius=3)
plt.show()
```

This throws an error:

```
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

and then produces a blank plot box

(I can't embed an image yet so here's the link) 
[Blank Plot Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFYTH.png)

Ideally I'd like them to all be subplots, but at this stage I'd take a series of individual plots. The other examples I've found don't deal with unique values for a key (County).

Comment: What is `mdfgroup`? You may want to read  [mcve].

Comment: Oops. `mdfgroup` is the Dataframe listed. Updated post to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
Ncounties = len(mdfgroup.County.unique())
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, Ncounties, figsize=(3*Ncounties,3), subplot_kw={'aspect':'equal'})
for ax,(groupname,subdf) in zip(axs,mdfgroup.groupby('County')):
    ax.pie(subdf.ServiceCt, labels=subdf.Service)
    ax.set_title(groupname)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Seeing it written out it makes total sense now. Determine how many unique counties there are, make that many subplots then loop through and graph them.

Comment: In my case, the data point has a fair spread across different groups. Due to the aspect:equal argument, it does manage to keep my scatter plot readable, but changes the size of a subplot to a small rectangle compared to the other two subplots. How to fix this?

Comment: How would I adjust this for two levels of groupby such that there are 6 combinations and I want my shape of subplots to be (2,3)?

Answer (score 5):

#### Using matplotlib

A common approach is to iterate over the `groupby` of a column. Here the column to iterate over is the `"Country"`. You may first create a subplot grid with at least as many subplots as you have unique countries. Then you may iterate over the subplots and the groups simultaneously.
At the end there might be some empty subplot(s); those can be set invisible.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Country" : list("AAACCCDDDOWW"),
                   "Service" : list("LTV")*4,
                   "ServiceCt" : list(map(int, "114321111122"))})

cols = 3
g = df.groupby("Country")
rows = int(np.ceil(len(g)/cols))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=cols, nrows=rows)

for (c, grp), ax in zip(g, axes.flat):
    ax.pie(grp.ServiceCt, labels=grp.Service)
    ax.set_title(c)

if len(g) < cols*rows:    
    for ax in axes.flatten()[len(g):]:
        ax.axis("off")
        
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Using seaborn

This case is actually well suited to be used with seaborn's `FacetGrid`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"Country" : list("AAACCCDDDOWW"),
                   "Service" : list("LTV")*4,
                   "ServiceCt" : list(map(int, "114321111122"))})

def pie(v, l, color=None):
    plt.pie(v, labels=l.values)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Country")
g.map(pie, "ServiceCt", "Service" )
        
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Using pandas

Finally, one can do all in one line using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Country" : list("AAACCCDDDOWW"),
                   "Service" : list("LTV")*4,
                   "ServiceCt" : list(map(int, "114321111122"))})


df.pivot("Service", "Country", "ServiceCt").plot.pie(subplots=True, legend=False)
        
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Drat, beaten to the punch again!

Comment: Ok, I added a few other options to still let those answers be different.